# My console is flashing - Java - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I am running a simple java program in eclipse, when I run it, the console flashes what it should, then it disappears.

```
public class apples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int age = 60;
        if (age < 50) {
            System.out.println("You are young");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You are old");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is immediately terminating after printing what needed to be printed. You can use several methods to keep the console on the screen.

Your program is immediately terminating after printing what needed to be printed. You can use several methods to keep the console on the screen. One possibility is to use

```
while(true);
```

to stop the application from exiting. Beware that you should only use this for debugging methods!

Another, probably better, way is to ask for input before closing the window.

Simply read a line from standard input. Your program will wait until you type something and only then exit.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // create a scanner that will read from standard input
String s = sc.nextLine(); // You don't even need to save the return value of
                          // sc.nextLine() here
```

Comment: Can you tell me? I am just learning java, so if you could explain what to do, that would be helpful, thanks :)

Comment: A quick mention of at least one of those methods would make this a better answer...

Comment: My apologies, I'm on bad internet and it keeps disconnecting. I have updated the answer.